# Search posts/questions only with specific tags

Tags: support, tags, search

As I understand it, the search box up top searches across all tags. And from browsing, it's straightforward showing all questions within a tag when you click on said tag.

I want to know if it's possible to browse questions tagged both **[vim]** and **[perl]**?

Is it possible to narrow down the results by search questions with specific tags?

This would be a nice to have and would come in handy when searching across a topic that covers two different tags.

Comment: Obviously you haven't even tried the search here on Meta. You should. Order some sides too.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/search-among-tags-prequel/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/search-among-tags-redux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following did the trick for me:

> [**[vim]** and **[perl]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+and+%5Bperl%5D)

Comment: looks "and" in between tags is not required. "[vim] [perl] gvim" searches for "gvim" in all questions tagged with vim and perl